# How to define a function that using extern "C" modifier

Tags: c, dll

In a DLL, a function is exported, and it is defined as:

```
extern "C" ULONGLONG WINAPI MyFun(CONST LPVOID lpParam);
```

Now in My app, I need to get the address of the function and invoke it, so I use

```
typedef ULONGLONG (WINAPI *MyFun) (CONST LPVOID lpParam);
```

and use

```
lpMyFun = (MyFun)GetProcAddress(hDLL, "MyFun");
```

In such a way, there is no way to put the extern "C" modifier in the typedef codeline, I using

```
extern "C" typedef ULONGLONG (WINAPI *MyFun) (CONST LPVOID lpParam);
```

but that will cause compiler error.

How to solve the problem?

Thanks

Comment: `extern "C"` only affects how the function's name is mangled, not the calling convention. Ergo, you do not need `extern "C"` at all with this approach.

Comment: If I read your code correctly, then you don't need the `extern "C"` in your code, as you don't actually link with the DLL directly. The `extern "C"` specifier in the DLL is for the compiler to not mangle the name of `MyFun`.